# Ajax no refresca página

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo un modal llamado "modalVe" que tiene un botón dentro llamado "bntDos". Al pulsar el botón ejecutar una instrucción PHP en la base de datos (que he comprobado que lo hace bien). Esta función no devuelve nada. Simplemente actualiza un registro en la BD.
El modal, además, se tiene que cerrar al pulsar el botón mencionado. Para ello tengo este script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#bntDos").click(function(){
    $("#modalVerBillete").modal('hide')
    cargarHoja();

});
```

});

Además de cerrar el modal, llama a una función que contiene el Ajax para refrescar la tabla sin cargar la página. El problema es que en el primer click no funciona (no recarga la tabla) pero en los sucesivos si.

```
function cargarHoja(){

    var exp=$("#selectExpedi").val();
    console.log(exp);
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:'hoja.php',
        data: {'exp':exp},

        success: function(data) {

            $('#contenidoTabla').html(data);

        }        

    });
}
```

¿Que hago mal?

Comment: Veo algo raro en la función `marcaDos`: asigna un event listener al botón `btnDos`, pero en principio ahí ya se ha pulsado y por eso se hace la llamada AJAX... sin ver el código completo no sabría decirte qué falla pero deberías revisar la lógica

Comment: Es contradictorio leer algo como *Ajax no refresca la página*. Precisamente Ajax existe para que la página no se refresque y poder actualizar su contenido sin tener que refrescar.

Comment: Hola. El event listener del btbDos lo tenia fuera de la función y hace lo mismo. Lo habia metido por probar algo distinto.

Comment: @A. Cedano, tienes razón en lo que dices. Es una manera incorrecta de expresarme. Soy autodidacta y estoy empezando con esto. Disculpa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo un par de cosas que te pueden dar problemas. La primera, que también ha mencionado Pablo Lozano es que estás declarando el evento onclick del botón "bntDos". Sospecho que ese botón tiene un atributo onclick que llama a la función "marcaDos", o algo similar. Lo que pasa al hacerlo así es que cuando haces click la primera vez en el botón se llama a marcaDos y se define un nuevo listener. A la segunda veces que hagas click, se ejecutará la función marcaDos y la función anónima que cierra el modal. De ahí que no se comporte igual la primera y sucesivas veces. De hecho, cada vez que pulses el botón va a crear un listener nuevo, por lo que cada vez va a tratar de ocultar el modal 2, 3, 4, veces... Eso podría ser problemático si añades más cosas en esa función anónima. Intenta definir ese listener en un único sitio, y antes de que se pulse el botón.

Por otra parte estás encadenando dos llamadas Ajax, si la segunda no se ejecuta puede ser porque la primera haya dado error. Aunque en tu servidor se haya guardado tu dato correctamente, si este no responde con un código de error a tu llamada Ajax, no se va a ejecutar tu función cargarHoja. Esto puede pasar por muchos motivos. Por ejemplo si tu server guarda en base de datos la entrada y después manda un mail, si falla el envío de email puede que recibas un fallo aunque hayan quedado bien guardados. Puedes poner un callback de error en tu primera llamada ajax para depurar si recibe un error o un éxito.

También deberías considerar que si encadenas llamadas Ajax y falla la segunda, ¿qué pasa con la primera? ¿Hay que cancelar la acción? No hay nada malo en encadenarlas, pero si no vas a hacer un procesamiento en el frontend de la respuesta y simplemente vas a volver a llamar al backend con lo recibido, ¿por qué no haces una única llamada y que el server haga las dos cosas de una tacada?

Por último, lo normal es que se oculte el modal una vez acabadas las llamadas ajax, en tu caso supongo que sería, en la primera llamada si ha habido error, y en la segunda llamada tanto si ha habido éxito como si ha habido error.

Comment: Gracias. Habia editado la pregunta con alguna corrección que he hecho antes de leer tu respuesta. Voy a analizar lo que dices.